# sigma js: how to keep edge selected onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, sigma.js

I am using the latest http://sigmajs.org/ library with EdgeHover enabled. However, I wish to change the color of an edge red once it is clicked (until another edge is clicked):

```
s.bind('clickEdge', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('metadata').innerHTML = e.data.edge;
    console.log(e.data.edge.hover_color = 'red');
});
```

- This makes an edge color red when i click it, but only on hover. How can I keep it red until another edge is clicked?
- Also, this keeps all edges that were once clicked to be red on hover, but I only want to one that is currently clicked (selected) to be red. Once another edge is selected, I want to hover color of the previously selected edge to go back to default `#000`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can keep on selected variable and toggle while click edge event happens

```
s.bind('clickEdge', function(e) {
        // Get Edge 
        if( !e.data.edge.selected  ){
          e.data.edge.color = '#F491A4';
          e.data.edge.selected = true;

        }else{
          e.data.edge.color = 'blue';
          e.data.edge.selected = false;
        }

        s.refresh();        
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks @Sumeet, however (please see here https://imgur.com/ELpBIeF) this only colors the very thin border of the edge red. How can I have the whole edge red? I only see the `color` property?

Comment: you can apply size to edge like  e.data.edge.size = < some big size > and do refresh @Pr0no

Comment: I'm so sorry, @Sumeet, but changing the size doesnt work; i keep getting only very thin borders at both sides of the edge. Unless the edge is very thin, then the whole line turns red. Any ideas? I have been looking for any other property to change, but I do not find any other property than "color".